# How to get matching color for #f20044

Tags: css, colors, pie-chart, c3.js

I have created a Pie chart using C3.JS. The code is working fine but the only problem is with the colors. My website is of the color `#f20044`. The C3.JS pie chart by default generates its own colours like red, blue, green which seems not matching for my website. 
One solution what C3 provides is that we have to provide our own custom colors for pie chart slices.

Can anyone please tell me how to create matching color to #f20044.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a colour scheme for your pie chart, try using [Adobe Color CC](https://color.adobe.com/). It will output complimentary colours based on your primary colour.

For example, the [triad color rule](https://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel/?base=2&rule=Triad&selected=0&name=My%20Color%20Theme&mode=rgb&rgbvalues=0.8862745098039215,0,0.4549019607843137,1,0.8947687696262392,0.09999999999999998,1,0,0.5132743362830752,0.07999999999999999,0.7166092221703366,0.8,0.03500000000000003,0.6229793510323247,0.7&swatchOrder=0,1,2,3,4) could work for your pie chart.